# Regarding orderer container in hyperledger-fabric

Tags: docker, containers, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

this is the error i am facing][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghx6G.jpg)I am trying to setup multi channel network, every thing was working fine except my Orderer was getting exited immediately. As there is no Orderer I could not proceed further. My setup consists of 3 ORGs and 1 peer for each ORG. So there should be 5 docker container processes including Orderer and cli where as when I was checking with docler ps command there were only 4 containers, docker ps -a was showing orderer Exited. Then I removed 3rd ORG from the setup and this issue got fixed. But now when I am trying other steps like creating channels, updating anchors, joining the channel etc. in between the cli is getting exited (but not immediately like orderer). I thought this could be RAM issue and so I removed the 3rd ORG. Just wanted to confirm is this issue related to memory (RAM)? I am setting up this on ubuntu VM with 8 GB total RAM.

Comment: Please don't post images. Your post should be self container (not relying on links) and errors/code should be copied as text into your post

Comment: You have to post a log of the dead orderer container to get an answer. Looking at the this information, I can infer that the genesis block is wrong by seeing that only orderer die.

Comment: Got this after log:Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.certification-network.com")
panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed:

Answer (score 0):

Try   `docker logs container-name or container id.`

This command prints the logs of that container, then you can verify why it's failing

Comment: Got this after log:Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority (possibly because of "x509: ECDSA verification failure" while trying to verify candidate authority certificate "ca.certification-network.com") panic: Failed validating bootstrap block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed

Comment: Accept my answer if your problem is resolved Thanks. Also you can ask questions on https://chat.hyperledger.org/